# Create new panda dataframe with fixed distance using interpolate

Tags: pandas, interpolation

I have a dataframe of the following form.

```
df =     {'X': [0, 3, 6, 7, 8, 11],
         'Y1': [8, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1.5],
         'Y2': [1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5]}
```

I would like to create a new dataframe where I use interpolate where 'X' is stepping in fixed steps [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10].
To find the new 'Y' values I need to find f(x)=Y1 and then I can evaluate for each step in X. But since I have many Y's I think there must be a more clever way to do this.

Comment: What is your f(x) function? 
So if I understand correctly, you want to find for which of these Ys applies the following: f(x)==Y

Comment: A simple linear function would be ok. The work around I am using right now is to take the values for each column and then using numpy.interp. Then I can evaluate for the all the X's I am interested in and then create a new dataframe. I was looking into re-index the dataframe for X but the point is that I have many X's and I only need values for specific steps.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was the following:

```
step_size = 0.25
no_steps = int(np.floor(max(b['X'])/step_size))
for i in range(0,no_steps+1):
    b = b.append({'X' : 0.25*i, 'StepNo' : 10, 'PointNo' : 23+i}, ignore_index=True)
b = b.sort_values(['X'])
b = b.set_index(['X'])
c = b.interpolate('index')
c = c.reset_index()
c = c.sort_values(['PointNo'])
```

So first I define step size. Then I calculate number of steps. Then I append the steps into the dataframe. Sort the dataframe and reindex so I can use interpolate using 'index' as values.